# Kotlin's Android Extensions and variables

Tags: android, kotlin

Before Kotlin, Android developers supposed to save reference to the Activity's Views in a variable like this:

```
Button fooBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_foo)
```

to reduce the amount of the boiler-plate code and the number of `findViewById` calls.

With the introduction of the [Kotlin's Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) we can reference the same Button by simply using:

```
btn_foo
```

---

**Questions:**

1. Does the `btn_foo` have a reference to the Button saved, or does it call `findViewById` every time?
2. Do developers still suppose to use variables to store `btn_foo` to improve app's performance, or just use it directly in the code?

---

**Edit:** there is [an explanation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#under-the-hood) how Extensions work, however it is still a bit unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the Kotlin Android Extension (KAE) developers [Ihor Kucherenko](https://medium.com/@ihorkucherenko) confirmed that:

- KAE will keep a reference to the view after the first call, instead of using `findViewById` all the time. That works **only** for `Activities` and `Fragments`.
- KAE will not cache data and will use `findViewById` every time for any other element (except for an `Activity`/`Fragment`).

So in case you are going to init a `ViewHolder`:

```
class FooViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(day: FooItem.Day) {
        btn_foo.text = day.title
    }
}
```

Decompile into Java call will look like:

```
((Button)this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_foo)).setText((CharSequence)day.getTitle());
```

which is exactly what you want to avoid.

The developers might be aware of this.

---

**Conclusion**: fill free to use KAE without any additional variables, but only for your `Activitiies`/`Fragments`.

Comment: Why limited to only `Activities` and `Fragments`? Its because they have easy access to `Context`?

Comment: @Tuby it might be related to the `Context`, and to the way Kotlin create extension-funtions (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#under-the-hood). There is a GitHub PR that addresses the issue and makes it available to use KAE for elements like a `ViewHolder` (https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/pull/33). However it is inactive for a year now.

Comment: Also, with a proper way of using Google Data Binding library and the MVVM pattern - there is no need for `findViewById`. I am personally waiting for the Architecture Components to become stable, so it implements data-binding, after which I am going to move my project to use it.

Answer (score 5):

It's cached, so `findViewById` isn't called every time you need it. Storing the variable won't definitely improve the app's performance